# How do you determine surjectivity from a function with combinations, such as $f(a,b) = \binom{a}{b}$?

Tags: functions, combinations

Define a function $f \colon \mathbb Z_+^2 \to \mathbb Z_+$ by:

$$f(a,b)=\begin{cases}
\binom{a}{b},\quad & \text{if } a\geqslant b\\
\binom{b}{a},\quad & \text{if } b < a
\end{cases}$$

From this how would I begin to prove that the function $f$ is surjective?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. To show that $f$ is onto, you have to give for any $n \in \mathbf Z^+$ a pair $(a,b) \in (\mathbf Z^+)^2$ such that $f(a,b) = n$. It may be helpful to remember the value of $\binom n1$.